# Удаленное сообщение

Tags: поддержка, удаление-ответов

Скажите, а почему было удалено моё сообщение из топика  [Не получается создать таблицу c Hibernate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506646/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-c-hibernate/515050#515050)

Comment: Скоро у вас будет 50 репутации и можно будет спокойно задавать уточняющие вопросы в комментариях. Пока что нельзя, таково ограничение для всех новых участников.

Comment: В будущем если у вас будут вопросы о работе сайта - задавайте их сразу на Мете (это здесь, `meta.ru.stackoverflow.com`), а не на основном сайте. Ну и добро пожаловать )

Comment: Понял, спасибо, Ник.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, там написано "преобразовано в комментарий", но комментария нет. Почему комментарий удалили?

Comment: @Qwertiy спрашивайте у автора комментария, почему он удалил )

Comment: @Qwertiy, да это я его удалил, не разобравшись с интерфейсом. Со временем освоюсь)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так ведь удалённые комментарии видят только модераторы, соответственно, я не вижу, кто его удалил. Я вижу только удалённый ответ с пометкой о преобразовании в комментарий.

Comment: @AlexanderTsukanov, ясно)

Comment: мне повезло в своё время. мой ответ с пробелами в ссылках для обхода ограничений [отформатировали](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/64292), и я получил за него 4 плюса, что позволило преодолеть ограничения для новичков. Но вообще новым участникам здесь трудно, он мало что могут. Надеюсь, уточняющие комментарии в ответах хоть переносятся в комментарии?

Comment: @СашаЧерных да, у модераторов есть кнопка "преобразовать в комментарий", и они (мы) ей активно пользуются в ответ на тревоги "не является ответом".

Comment: @PashaPash I've got button in my toolbar and I'm not afraid to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Понял, спасибо.